# What electric component is this? (its on an old electric organ)

Tags: capacitor, identification, components

I'm trying to find out what this is and where I can buy one. To me, this looks like a capacitor, but I'm no expert. After using a multimeter, this seems to be the cause for the organ not turning on. (it's an old electric organ that I bought to try to fix) Can someone help me?

[image]

Comment: That is an electrolytic capacitor. Just like the grey one with 1000mFD on it  in the botttom right corner. Electrolytic capacitors are notorious for failing after a while and are often the cause of problems with old power supplies.

Comment: Thanks :) I'm guessing that without soldering it out, I can't tell the milliFarad that this one has? correct?

Comment: Welll....l desoldering does seems much easier then removing the heat sink which prevents you seeing the text :-) Don't forget to check the voltage too.

Comment: Thanks for the help and advice !! I appreciate ;)

Comment: yes the value is written on part that is not visible

Comment: And if you think it's bad, you need to take it out anyway.  Be sure to get a replacement that's rated for the same or higher voltage (and the same capacitance, of course).

Comment: Thank you, guys! yes, at least using the multimeter the only spot that there is no flow in the circuit is between what is connected through the capacitor so I'm hoping that this is the only issue with the organ!

Comment: Your not looking for a "flow" in the capacitor.  With power applied you should be able to measure a controlled DC voltage across the capacitor.  Large capacitors like this are often used in the power supply sections of devices. If the capacitor has a problem it could be shorted or open.  Check the output voltage from the board first then work back from there.  The board itself might be marked near the connectors with the expected output voltage.

Answer (score 1):

As answered in the comments, it's capacitor and the ratings will be on the side you can't see without removing it. The important question though, is why do you think it's the problem? What tests did you perform? You might be barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: Correct me If I'm wrong, but using a multimeter, I should be able to see that there is flow between both ends of the capacitor correct? What a did was to check from the beginning to end where the flow stopped, what so far the only spot where that happens is with the capacitor.

Comment: Well, sorta. A capacitor for practical purposes does not pass direct current, except for leakage, so depending on exactly how you checked, what you saw may mean nothing. With a capacitor the size this is likely to be, if it were disconnected from the rest of the circuit and you checked it with the ohms setting of your meter, it should show a low (ish) resistance that drifted up to a very high (ish) resistance as it charged. This is much easier to see with an analogue meter, which may not be what you have. If it is dead shorted or dead open you should be able to see that with your multimeter.